# Align Image to Top Left of the Page with no margins

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I'm trying to align an image (3200x2368) to the top of the page. It is not aligned and I don't know what I can try more than this.
Anything I tried doesn't make the picture to align on top and on the left side without any margins.
Why is that and how can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, pgffor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\noindent
\begin{figure}[t]
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=7in,valign=t]{test.jpg}
  \caption{Test Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the test image

[image]

Ant this is how the document looks like

[image: document]

Comment: `a4paper, total={6in, 8in}`  ?? what  size do you want the page to be, A4 or 6" by 8"  ? either way you specfy the image as 7" wide starting at the left margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tikz` package to align the top left corner of the image to the top left corner of the page.

The image is wider than the width of the page (597.5pt). Using `width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio` will make it fit.

To accommodate the option bellow the image, add a suitable vertical space `\vspace{<space>}`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, pgffor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{tikz}% added<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}    
    
\pagestyle{empty}%
\noindent
\begin{figure}      
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north west, align=left, inner sep=0] at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{test.jpg}};      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{330pt}% move the caption down <<<<
    \caption{Test Caption}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply overlaps the margins while maintaining the distance to the caption.  Without adding some text, the figure becomes a [p] float and is centered on the page instead of at the top.  Be warned that graphicx uses some of registers 0-9. but I forget which ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% not used
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \setlength{\dimen9}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep}% vertical offset
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \setlength{\dimen8}{\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin}% left margin
  \else
    \setlength{\dimen8}{\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\dimen7}{\dimexpr \paperwidth-\textwidth-\dimen8}% right margin
  \vskip-\dimen9\hskip-\dimen8
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
  \hskip-\dimen7
  \caption{Test Caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-4]% wihtout the text, it bcomes a [p] float
\end{document}
```